# About SQL Server stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to divide the page, but the following stored procedure is wrong, because use the `@size`, and how is the right way to accomplish this stored procedure

thanks!!!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE message_devidepage
    @size int,
    @page int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP @size * from   --point out @size is wrong 
        (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY createTime desc) AS RowNumber,* FROM message
        ) ed
    WHERE RowNumber > @size*(@page-1);
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the variable in parenthesis, like:

```
declare @i int
set @i = 1
select top (@i) * from sys.tables
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `TOP` requires a constant value. However, you can use `SET ROWCOUNT`, see [SET ROWCOUNT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this:

```
SELECT * from 
......
WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @size*(@page-1) AND @size*(@page)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or higher you can use RowNumber. for earlier versions of SQL server, you can set RowCount.